# Change time format from one to another

Tags: python, datetime

I need to covert time that is in this format:

2021-10-20T09:35:06.615-07:00

to this format:

10/20/2021:09:35:06

I have been playing around with datetime.datetime.strptime() since I am using Python 2.7, but I have had no luck.

Which method will help me do the conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use
[python-dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil)

```
import datetime
import dateutil.parser
datestring = '2021-10-20T09:35:06.615-07:00'
d = dateutil.parser.parse(datestring)
```

you try to parse timezone:

```py
def parse_timezone(datestring):
    tzchar =  datestring[-6];
    datestr = datestring[0:-6];
    tzstr = datestring[-5:];
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f');
    if tzchar == '+':
        d =  d + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(tzstr[0:2]), minutes = int(tzstr[3:]));
    else:
        d =  d - datetime.timedelta(hours=int(tzstr[0:2]), minutes = int(tzstr[3:]));
    
    return d;

d = parse_timezone('2021-10-20T09:35:06.615-07:00');
print(d.strftime('%M/%d/%Y:%H:%M:%S'));
```

Comment: I need to stick to Python standard library. I am running my code in the cloud, and installing 3rd party libraries like dateutil is a royal pain. It's doable, but a pain. dateutil appears to be a 3rd party library.

Comment: Thank you! This works.